# Performing a cryptographic operation on number of packet segments?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

Suppose I have n number of packet segments.
I want to encrypt data from offset c1 to c2 and c1 and c2 can be in any segment. The 1st segment is always greater than following segments since the other segments after the 1st segments only contain data.

```
-------------------  Seg 1
---c1--------        Seg 2
----------c2-        Seg 3
```

Also the encryption I'm doing  can be done only in multiple of 16 bytes. So if in 2nd segment the leftover length is not a multiple I'm left with 1 - 15 bytes.  So how to continue encryption in the following segment?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a padding to complete the 16 byte chunk and do the encryption.
Afterwards add the information about number of bytes padded in the header and send it across to the destination where it could read and take care of it at the time of decryption.